# Ceiling fan + dimmable lights + old wiring?

Tags: lighting, ceiling-fan, dimmer-switch

I want to have my cake and eat it too. Is there any way to accomplish this?

I have an old ceiling light circuit. There is a switch going to a (broken) fan on the ceiling, with lights in it. Since the fan is broken (I'm not sure how, it predates my living here), and I wanted dimmable lights, I disconnected the fan motor in the fan/light assembly and installed a dimmer in the light switch.

However, summer is coming and I'd like a functional ceiling fan. I expect to have to replace the entire fan/light unit with a working one, and to have to replace the dimmer with a normal switch so as not to fry the fan. Is there any way for me to get both dimmable lights and a ceiling fan on one circuit? I'm okay with paying a little extra for some remote-control gizmo or something to control the dimming, if there exists a device like that.

I'm renting, so any modifications I make that aren't strictly positive (e.g. a working ceiling fan instead of a broken one) should be reversible.

Comment: How many wires run between the switch and the fan? Can you post photos of the insides of the boxes involved?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Note:** Depending on location and other factors (e.g., your lease) you may not be allowed to make **any** electrical system changes in a rented apartment. So any changes recommended by me or anyone else should be considered as "maybe I can do them myself or maybe I have to pay an electrician to do it".

Traditionally, a ceiling fan + light could be controlled one of two ways:

- **Two** switches, with **two switched hot** wires. One switched hot would control the fan, one would control the lights and they would share a neutral. Putting a dimmer switch on the **lighting only** switch would work just fine, because it would control only the lights and not the fan. Based on your description (including "disconnected the fan motor"), I don't think you have this configuration.
- **One switch**, with pull chains for the light and fan. This sounds like what you have. You can't use a dimmer in this configuration because whenever you dim lights you would cause big problems for the fan motor, as controlling speed of a fan requires a different kind of control than a normal dimmer.

There are two solutions:

- **Smart Switch** - Get a smart switch that has a switch module with two switches, one including a dimmer, and with a remote box that connects to the fan/light. A smart switch can control multiple devices all over a single wire. If you want the option to connect "anything", that is the way to do it. But fortunately, new fans anticipate these requirements, so...
- **New Fan/Light with Remote** - For example, picked at random [Hunter Channing 54 in. LED Indoor Easy Install Brushed Nickel Ceiling Fan with HunterExpress feature set](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Hunter-Channing-54-in-LED-Indoor-Easy-Install-Brushed-Nickel-Ceiling-Fan-with-HunterExpress-feature-set-53367/304357282) and checking the installation guide:

  - Remote controls fan speed **and** light dimming
  - **Includes single-switch instructions** on page 6 of the [installation guide](https://images.homedepot-static.com/catalog/pdfImages/7b/7bdba727-b558-4d1b-a785-7043f73d204b.pdf)

Bottom line: Get a fan/light that includes a remote **and** single-switch instructions and you're all set.

Comment: I bought a new fan/light with a remote, and when I was uninstalling the old one, I found something that looked suspiciously like a remote module in the very top. Sure enough, my old fan was remote-controlled, and worked after all once I got a remote for it.